# disable drag and drop image quill js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, quill

How to disable drag and drop of quill js (angular NG QUILL)
without disable the formats image?

look screen:
[image]

Comment: Options for Quill: https://quilljs.com/docs/configuration/ - Pay attention to the format option. Other than that, I don't see any other included options to disable the drag and drop.

Comment: @RyanC that sucks so much, I think I will go with froala editor

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by wrapping the editor in a div and preventing the default nature of drop event.

Here's an example...

```
<div onDrop={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
  <ReactQuill {...props}/> //Your editor component
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue using "react-quill-with-table" due to a module called "uploader" enabled by default.

Fixed by overriding it:

```
class ByeByeUploader {}

Quill.register({
  "modules/uploader": ByeByeUploader
}, true);
```

Alternatively, it seems to provide a "handler" option which can be overridden to do nothing:

```
<ReactQuill
  modules={{
    uploader: {
      handler: ()=>{}
    }
  }}
...
```

Finally, if your issue is not coming from this module I suggest you set a DOM breakpoint on the quill container DIV for subtree modifications to get a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Quill editor but I fixed the issue.
Please see my code:

```
<div id="quill-editor" (dragover)="false"></div>
```

So if you put `(dragover)="false"` in your editor `div`, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Along with `(dragover)="false"` you can also add below code inside  onEditorCreated(quill) event handler to disable copy-paste of images.

```
quill.clipboard.addMatcher('IMG', (node, delta) => {
       const Delta = Quill.import('delta');
       return new Delta().insert('');
})
quill.clipboard.addMatcher('PICTURE', (node, delta) => {
        const Delta = Quill.import('delta');
        return new Delta().insert('');
})
```

Sharing links to related threads,

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1108

[Remove colors when pasting on ngx quill field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607857/remove-colors-when-pasting-on-ngx-quill-field)

Answer (score 0):

Disable default bahaviour of image using following html, javascript

```
$('img').on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a browser behavior. `Quill` does nothing with this.

```js
// 此处用于禁用拖拽事件
window.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
  e = e || event
  e.preventDefault()
}, false)
window.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  e = e || event
  e.preventDefault()
}, false)
```

Comment: This is a browser behavior.