# Remove colors when pasting on ngx quill field

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I am using the `ngx-quill` editor and so far it has all the features that I need. However, I don't see any options on how to remove the background colors and font colors of the text coming from the clipboard.
 I want to retain all the other formatting except the colors. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10):

For anyone having the same issue with me, I managed to find a workaround for this.

On my view :

```
<quill-editor (onEditorCreated)='editorInit($event)'></quill-editor>
```

On my Controller

```
editorInit(quill: any){
    quill.clipboard.addMatcher(Node.ELEMENT_NODE, function(node, delta){
      delta.forEach(e => {
        if(e.attributes){
          e.attributes.color = '';
          e.attributes.background = '';
        }
      });
      return delta;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Glad you not only found the solution to your problem, but also shared it here with the community. Thank you. I should only add one small detail: Next time you ask something, please try to be clearer and provide more details about your problem. As a tip, read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Hope to see you here again, okay? See you later.

Comment: Please mark as verified it's a working code.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// If you want to remove complete formating use this code.
onEditorCreated(quill : Quill) {
    quill.clipboard.addMatcher(Node.ELEMENT_NODE, (node, delta) => {          
      delta.forEach(e => {
        if (e && e.attributes) {
          delete e.attributes;
        }     
      });
      return delta;
    });
}
```

```js
// If you want to remove individual formating use this code.
onEditorCreated(quill : Quill) {
    quill.clipboard.addMatcher(Node.ELEMENT_NODE, (node, delta) => {          
      delta.forEach(e => {
        if (e && e.attributes) {
          e.attributes.color = '';
          e.attributes.background = '';
          e.attributes.fontSize = '1rem';
          e.attributes.fontWeight = 'normal';
          e.attributes.header = 0;
        }     
      });
      return delta;
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. Just an addition: Instead of re-setting chosen properties, you can also turn it around: keep chosen properties and remove all others: if(e && e.attributes){ for (let prop in e.attributes) { switch(prop) { case 'bold': case 'background': case 'color': case 'link': break; default: delete e.attributes[prop]; break; } } }

Answer (score 0):

- If you don't want to remove color and background using event listeners as mentioned in @manoyanx's answer, you can use

  ```
    const myQuillEditorFormats = ["background", "bold", "color", "font", "code", "italic", "link", "size", "strike", "script", "underline", "blockquote", "header", "indent", "list", "align", "direction", "code-block", "formula", "image", "video"];
  ```
- In the above **myQuillEditorFormats** array, I have added all default quill editor options. You can specifically remove the options which you don't want.
- Then in your NgModule's imports

  ```
    QuillModule.forRoot({ formats: quillEditorFormats })
  ```

Source: https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/